# VBA Shell command no longer working

Tags: vba, shell, excel

Heyho,

earlier today I ran into some issues with the Shell command in VBA using excel2010 64bit.
I have fixed them for now with a hardcoded workaround, but would like to know why it suddenly stopped working.

Here the code snipped:

```
dim mypath as string
dim myfolder as string

mypath = "D:\somefolder\"
myfolder = "somesubfolder\"

Shell mypath & myfolder & "some.bat"
```

Until 2 weeks ago, this was consistently executing the bat, but then suddenly stopped working.

I have played around with it for a bit and checked other syntaxes I was using with the shell command and have yet to make any sense of it.
Whenever I tried to execute this snipped I would get a

```
"runtime error 5, invalid procedure call or argument"
```

However, it was working two weeks ago, and I haven't touched the file. According to the MS documentation all other arguments for Shell are optional so that also cannot be the problem.

In the end, instead of looping through my directories, I hardcoded the paths in multiple commands like this:

```
Shell """fullpath_to_.bat-files"""
```

Funny thing is, I have multiple other VBA scripts where I actually use the old syntax I described further up, meaning combining strings exactly as described in the first example.

I checked whether the paths were build any different or if it is because of me changing hard-drives for this particular script in the .bat but could not find anything that would give me a clue as to why the old syntax I was using is no longer working.

I also checked if my included libraries or anything got tangled up but nothing.
I'm completely at a loss.
The script is running now, but I want to understand why it stopped working.

Comment: Strange - I can't duplicate the problem. A couple of suggestions: 1. "path" and "folder" are VBA properties and shouldn't be used as variable names, try changing them to "myPath" and "myFolder". 2. Your hardcoded string contains extra quotations preventing issues from spaces in the path: try the same for the initial code, like this: `Shell """" & myPath & myFolder & "a b.bat" & """"`

Comment: @paulbica : Sorry my example was probably misleading, I didn't use path and folder a variable names, but cryptic stuff for the loop, thought that would make it clearer. The problem is I cannot reproduce this problem in other files as well. And the quotation marks are, for some reason, required for this path, I also have working snippets in other files, that only use single quotes, but have spaces in the path and still work fine.

Comment: Any idea what was causing it?